# Contact form won't submit on button press

Tags: php, html, contact-form

Struggling to get my contact form to send. I've pasted the code below

When i fill in the form and push send, nothing happens. I've tried using a button as opposed to an input submit but that still does nothing. I've had forms like this before work fine but now I just can't get this to send. Any clues?

```html
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="process.php">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group" id="name-field">
        <div class="form-input">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-name" name="form-name" placeholder="Full Name">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group" id="email-field">
        <div class="form-input">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="form-email" name="form-email" placeholder="Email address">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group" id="name-field">
        <div class="form-input">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-address" name="form-address" placeholder="Address of the works">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group" id="email-field">
        <div class="form-input">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-phone" name="form-phone" placeholder="Phone number">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group" id="phone-field">
        <div class="form-input">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-subject" name="form-subject" placeholder="Description of the works required">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group" id="message-field">
        <div class="form-input">
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" id="form-message" name="form-message" placeholder="Further Information"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="SEND FORM" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<?php
           {
          $to = "info@blank.co.uk";
          $subject = "Contact Page from ";
          $headers  = "From: A T L <noreply@blank.co.uk>\r\n";
         $headers .= "Reply-To: noreply@blank.co.uk\r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: noreply@blank.co.uk\r\n";
      $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";
      $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'form-name');
     $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'form-email');   
       $address = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'form-address');
       $telephone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'form-phone');
      $theirSub = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'form-subject');
      $message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'form-message');

     $message = 
     "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>Name: </span>"."<br />".$name."<br />"."<br />".
     "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>Email: </span>"."<br />".$email."<br />"."<br />".
     "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>Address: </span>"."<br />".$address."<br />"."<br />".
     "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>Telephone: </span>"."<br />".$telephone."<br />"."<br />".
     "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>Email: </span>"."<br />".$email."<br />"."<br />".
     "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>Subject: </span>"."<br />".$theirSub."<br />"."<br />".
     "<span style='font-weight: bold;'>Message: </span>"."<br />".$message."<br />"."<br />";

     mail($to, $subject,"We have received a message via the online form at www.blank.co.uk<br /><br />" . 
     $message, $headers);
     echo "Your message was successfully sent. Please <a href='contact.php'>click here</a> to return to the site.";
      ?>
       <?php  }
       ?>
```

Comment: What do you se if you press F12 before sending? Network tab should show the request to process.php

Comment: Is that php code block from process.php or is it from the same file as the form? If it's from the same file, you should change `action="process.php"` to `action=""`

Comment: On inspect element, it shows the process.php within the body markup but nothing happens on click. Process.php is a seperate file.

Comment: it does, just tested

Comment: Then why isn't it sending on my site?! I've deleted all cookies etc and still nothing is happening. It won't divert to the send message on button press. I've even tried using it on my phone as a seperate test and still nothing on button press.

Comment: Your code looks like your action needs to be `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" ` and not process.php - add an isset for subbut and add a name to the button: `<input name="subbut" type="submit" value="SEND FORM" />`

Comment: And try to `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to show the php error's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $message variable is used twice...  once to receive data from the form, and then you overwrite it?  You may want to use a different variable for that.  I changed to $msg.

Also, you have a lot of needless php tags.  Maybe try something a little cleaner like this to start:

```
<?php
$to = "info@blank.co.uk";
$subject = "Contact Page from ";
$headers  = "From: A T L <noreply@blank.co.uk>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: noreply@blank.co.uk\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: noreply@blank.co.uk\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'form-name');
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'form-email');   
$address = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'form-address');
$telephone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'form-phone');
$theirSub = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'form-subject');
$msg = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'form-message');

$message = 
"<span style='font-weight: bold;'>Name: </span>"."<br />".$name."<br />"."<br />".
"<span style='font-weight: bold;'>Email: </span>"."<br />".$email."<br />"."<br />".
"<span style='font-weight: bold;'>Address: </span>"."<br />".$address."<br />"."<br />".
"<span style='font-weight: bold;'>Telephone: </span>"."<br />".$telephone."<br />"."<br />".
"<span style='font-weight: bold;'>Email: </span>"."<br />".$email."<br />"."<br />".
"<span style='font-weight: bold;'>Subject: </span>"."<br />".$theirSub."<br />"."<br />".
"<span style='font-weight: bold;'>Message: </span>"."<br />".$msg."<br />"."<br />";

mail($to, $subject,"We have received a message via the online form at www.blank.co.uk<br /><br />" . $message, $headers);
echo "Your message was successfully sent. Please <a href='contact.php'>click here</a> to return to the site.";
?>
```

Comment: Still nothing, this doesn't send the form.

Comment: I have to pass out so can't go through the whole thing right now - but will try a little longer...  but I did notice a few other issues...  for example, on your filter_input, you don't specify a filter id, so the default is used (the default does nothing).  See php manual here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: Are php file and the html file both in the same folder? In the action field, the path is correct to the php file?  Maybe try the complete url:  https://example.com/process.php.   Also, is there any javascript running? Nothing like event.preventDefault(), etc?